# Real-Time Video Streaming from Webcam

Tags: c#, winforms, video-streaming

I am currently building a client-server network for real-time video calls. So far, I am able to stream video without voice:

```
private void connect_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
    nwStream = client.GetStream();
    Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendImage));
    thr.Start();
}

    private void SendImage()
    {
        while (true) { 
        try
        {
            byte[] test = ImageToByte(ReduceQuality(bmp));
            nwStream.Write(test, 0, test.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
```

How can I implement voice part? I thought about having another thread to read from microphone and send it also but than I can't ensure the synchronization between voice and the frame?

Comment: Easiest way is to send sound on a different port.  It is more complicated to send video and sound on same port.  You would have to put a header on each message indicating the size and if message was audio or video.

Comment: The only way I can think to ensure synchronization to have a timestamp in each class and match them again in the end client. Do you think this is a good way to do this?

Comment: If it is real time why do you think you need to synchronize?  Suppose you called somebody on a phone and also had a video on-line with person.  Is the phone and computer connection synchronized?  As long as the two ports are constantly sending there is no synchronization needed.  Both sound and video are electronically being sent over similar medium than there is not need to synchronize.  When the medium, is different, or you are sending chunk data with different block sizes (for audio and video) you may need to synchronize.

Comment: I am talking about having the sync between the audio and the image. I don't want to end up with an application with 3 seconds delay between the speech and the image.

Comment: Why would you think you would have a delay?  If the audio and video is traveling through the same electronic medium why you would have a different delay?  Yes the speed of sound and the speed of light is different through air.  Once you transmit sound and video over a Ethernet connection the delay is the same.  You've digitized both the sound and video and the delay is the same because you are sending bytes.